# How to make import.io retrieve data stored

Tags: import.io

Everytime I run the API in the android app, it runs the query itself and retrieve data from the website instead of the stored data, how do I make it retrieve the data stored to save running time?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't something you can do via the UI just yet, but it is coming!

If you have saved the results of your Extractor as a **dataset** you can do this via API:

To query a dataset, you need to query its "snapshot"...

First use the GetConnector API with the ID of your dataset:

http://api.docs.import.io/#!/Connector_Methods/getConnector

Note the snapshot ID

Use the ID of the dataset and the snapshot ID from the result and enter them here:

http://api.docs.import.io/#!/Connector_Methods/getDataSnapshot

This will return the data stored in your dataset.

Comment: I tried it however I keep getting access denied and 404 error code

Comment: In the second step, after inserting the publishSnapshot and the ID of the dataset to return the datastored

Comment: This is strange, I just tested it on one of my datasets and got no 404. Can you post the id of the original extractor?

Comment: I tested with a different extractor still didn't work, However the id is: 63b0a924-7d0d-42cc-abb1-b771f173dd2c

Comment: Strange, I have been able to get it to work.  First I duplicated your extractor, then put some urls into bulk extract. I then exported to import.io dataset. with the GUID of the dataset (not the extractor) I used the method that I posted as a solution.  Make sure you put the 'dataset' ID in the 'get connector' method. Then take the snapshot id from the result and use this and the dataset ID in the 'get data snapshot method'